# Quarkus: Routing messages to ActiveMQ

Tags: quarkus

I'd writing a Quarkus application which uses streams and send them to ActiveMQ as messages.

```
@Outgoing("my-stream")
public PublisherBuilder<String> source() {
        return ReactiveStreams.of("outgoing message");
}

@Incoming("my-stream")
@Outgoing("to-activemq")
@Broadcast
public String transform(String payload) {
        // I'll do some transformation here
        return "modified";
}
```

Then I have configured the outgoing part in the application.properties file:

```
mp.messaging.outgoing.to-activemq.connector=smallrye-amqp
mp.messaging.outgoing.to-activemq.address=destinationQueue
mp.messaging.outgoing.to-activemq.durable=true
```

So I'd expect to find messages in the "destinationQueue". However, looking at the AMQ console, what I can see is messages are not bound to a destination:

[image]

In practice, message end up to be counted as "Un routed message count".
Is there something wrong in my application.properties file?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't have experience in using AMQ, but are you sure that your source() method is triggered automatically  (or how does it get triggered) ? Add log statements and/or breakpoints on your methods and see what happens. And I assume that you also have configured the connection settings in application.properties ?